# Need help understanding char and int pointers

Tags: c, pointers

In this code to print the value of `int` and `char` pointer variables, why do I access them differently? For the `char` pointer I write `sampleclient` but for the `int` I write `*intid`. Why does one use `*` but not the other?

```
int main()
{
    char client[] = "ABCD";
    int intid = 10;

    samplepass(&client, &intid);

    return 0;   
}

void samplepass(char *sampleclient, int *intid)
{
    printf("%s %d\n", sampleclient, *intid);
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: One important thing to understand is that a `char` is *not* a "character".  It's a numeric value that is essentially a small `int`.  It's just that sometimes, in some contexts, a sequence of `char` locations are assigned values that represent printable characters.  But there is nothing in the `char` itself that identifies it as the letter "b" vs representing, say, your body temperature of 98.

Answer (score 8):

This is because `%s` format specifier expects a char pointer, while `%d` expects an integer argument. If you want to see the value of the **pointers** themselves(i.e. the address they point to) use `%p`.

Answer (score 1):

In C, you can't pass a string (character array) to a function like `printf`, so you do the next best thing: pass it its address in memory.  The function can then treat the memory address like an array using pointer arithmetic.  So the way `printf` reads strings is by taking in a pointer to the string.  Then `%s` displays the dereferenced string (`ABCD` here), not the pointer address (which you could get by using `%p` instead of `%s`).

The integer problem is more straightforward: the `*` in `*intid` means 'get the value stored at this address'.  That's why it prints out `10`, not the memory address.

The 'correct' format specifier to get a memory address  is `%p`.  But you could write:

```
int main()
{
    char client[] = "ABCD";
    int intid = 10;

    samplepass(&client, &intid);

    return 0;   
}

void samplepass(char *sampleclient, int *intid)
{
    printf("%d %d\n", sampleclient, intid);
}
```

On my machine, the output was

```
-2140958000 -2140958004
```

(and those are the addresses in memory of `client` and `intid`).  Substituting `%p` for `%d` gives nicely formatted pointers with a `0x` in front and conforms to the standard, so I'd use that.

Answer (score 0):

For an output that looks like:

ABCD 10

change your line

from `samplepass(&client,&intid);`
to  `samplepass(client,&intid);`